# Linq: Joining two tables

Tags: c#, linq

On my WPF Grid I am populating the following properties. The last two are coming from another table.  I would like to get the mapping rule from another table where `sourceelementid` in the transaction table equals the `id` of the `messagefield` table

```
public List<MessageFieldViewModel> GetAllViewModelMsgFields()
{
    messageFieldVModel = messageField.GetAllMessageField().Select(msgFields => new MessageFieldViewModel
    {
        Id = msgFields.Id,
        Code = msgFields.Code,
        Name = msgFields.Name,
        Position = msgFields.Position,
        Length = msgFields.Length,
        IsMapped = (transactionRuleList.Any(tr=> tr.SourceElementId ==msgFields.Id)),
        MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Where(mapRule => mapRule.MappingRule.Any(tr=> tr.SourceElementId ==msgFields.Id)),
    })
.ToList();
    return messageFieldVModel;
}
```

but the Mapping rule column throws error. Can some one help me ?

Comment: Can you post the inner exception please?

Comment: @Goanne here is the error : 'char' does not contain a definition for 'SourceElementId' and no extension method 'SourceElementId' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Ok, did you intend to add the last coma before closing the inner bracket? "msgFields.Id))," => "msgFields.Id))"

Comment: This is what I have :                                                    MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Where(mapRule => mapRule.MappingRule.Any(tr => tr.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id))
            })
        .ToList();

Comment: I found out what the problem is i will post solution shortly!  thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
      transactionRuleList = transationRuleViewModel.GetAllTranslationRules();
        messageFieldVModel = messageField.GetAllMessageField().Select(msgFields => new MessageFieldViewModel
        {
            Id = msgFields.Id,
            Code = msgFields.Code,
            Name = msgFields.Name,
            Position = msgFields.Position,
            Length = msgFields.Length,
            IsMapped = (transactionRuleList.Any(tr => tr.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id)),
            MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Any(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id)?transactionRuleList.First(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id).MappingRule:null
```